# SSIS Excel connection error "External table is not in the expected format."

Tags: ssis

Problem

-I have an excel spreadsheet generated a lotus app. It smells and looks like excel but Excel Source data flow source can not recognise it. When trying to select a table(tab) i get the following error message "External table is not in the expected format.”

-Opening the excel spreadsheet and save it again helps(File also reduces in size). But as dev we ara allegic to manual processes.

-I have tried to change the connection string using a variable

from

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\DataImport\Lotus.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES";
```

To

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\DataImport\Lotus.xls;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0;HDR=YES";
```

If i can avoid the script task that would be great

Comment: Do you know what version of Excel the Lotus generated spreadsheet targets? Is the data on multiple tabs or a single tab? Tab name(s) always the same? Safe to assume the source file is nothing we can examine to see why the driver is unhappy with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had to open and close the excel file manually saving. Those bugs that can't be fixed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, your post led me to open the excel file but my excel file was corrupt. I'm posting in case this helps someone else.